# How can I handle different statements in one command?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

How can I write the following code without multiple tedious assignments?

```
statement returns [Leaf node]
    :  assignment     {node = $assignment.node;}
    |  write          {node = $write.node;}
    |  writeln        {node = $writeln.node;}
    |  readBool       {node = $readBool.node;}
    |  readInt        {node = $readInt.node;}
    ;
```

Something like the following would be good enought.

```
statement returns [Leaf node]
    :  a=(assignment | write | writeln | ...) { //all statements returns `Leaf`
        node = $a.node; //but 'a' is just a `Tokien`, so we get compile error.
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible:

```
statement returns [Leaf node]
    :  a=(assignment | write | writeln | ...) { //all statements returns `Leaf`
        node = $a.node; //but 'a' is just a `Tokien`, so we get compile error.
    };
```

because the parenthesis might match more than one rule:

```
a=(a b | c d e | ...)
```

or parser- and lexer rules could be mixed:

```
a=(A b | C | d | ...)
```

You *can* do something like this though:

```
statement returns [Leaf node]
    :  (a=assignment | a=write | a=writeln | ...) 
       {
         $node = $a.node;
       };
```

But personally, I prefer what you posted first:

```
statement returns [Leaf node]
    :  assignment     {node = $assignment.node;}
    |  write          {node = $write.node;}
    |  writeln        {node = $writeln.node;}
    |  readBool       {node = $readBool.node;}
    |  readInt        {node = $readInt.node;}
    ;
```

Much more readable, IMHO.